# Sort shell object items

Tags: vbscript

I have a folder with files and this in a script:

```
Set shObj=CreateObject("shell.Application")
Set shFold=shObj.NameSpace(FolderName)
Set shFiles=shFold.Items
```

After that the `shFiles` are printed:

```
For each printfile in shFiles
  printfile.InvokeVerbEx "Print"

....so on...

Next
```

What i need is to sort the list of these files grabbed with `shFold.Items` so that I know that    `For each printfile in shfiles` will print them out in alphabetic order.

Any suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't look like VB.Net at all.  Actually looks more like VBScript than even VB6.

Comment: @BobRiemersma yes..thank you! you are right:( I pressed enter too fast on autosuggestion i guess.